# Text to far to the left

Tags: html

Text is all the way to the left on one of my inner pager. I have attached screenshots.

If someone can help that would be great.

[Website Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0SwB.png)
[HTML Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Eg4X.png)

Comment: This is because of your div classes.

Comment: Could you be any more specific? Are you using bootstrap? Probably I guess?

Comment: Please see [ask] and put a [mcve] in your question

Comment: It's to the left...where do you want it?

Answer (score 1):

Increase the height of the containing element and add equal padding to the left and the right. Example

```
height: 300px;
padding-right:50px;
padding-left:50px;
```

If you want to specifically center the text then you can add

```
text-align:center;
```

you could also alter the margin instead, its completely up to you and it would be helpful if you add your css into the question so that we can get a better understanding of why this problem is occurring. If you write the css of the code into the question then I can answer your question better